# I am trying to use the SharePoint ITransformableFilterValues multiple values in web part

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Here is my code:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
        }

        public bool AllowAllValue
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public bool AllowEmptyValue
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public bool AllowMultipleValues
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public string ParameterName
        {
            get { return "Label"; }
        }

        public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string> ParameterValues
        {
            get
            {
                string[] labels = { "01082-002", "01082-003" };
                return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(labels);
            }
        }
        [ConnectionProvider("Binder Label Filter", "ITransformableFilterValues", AllowsMultipleConnections = true)]
        public ITransformableFilterValues SetConnectionInterface()
        {
            return this;
        }
```

I am trying to passing in 2 different items to be used for filtering a list.  I can get it to work.  However, only the first item in the string array is actually being used in the filter.  Not real sure what I am missing.

Comment: Try the suggestions in this post - using your own implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735844/itransformablefiltervalues-interface-with-two-or-more-parameters-sharepoint-web

Comment: This implementation is for more than 1 filter.  I want to use a single filter with more than 1 value.

Comment: @Milton.Pulliza Hi Milton, I have the same problem. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your page and edit it.
2. Expand the menu on your filter provider web part, go through
   **'Connections'**, click on the connection you've previously established
   (with the filter-consumer part) and delete it by clicking **'Remove
   Connection'** in the pop-up window.
3. Re-establish the connection, but this time in the first pop-up
   choose the connection type to be **'Get Filter Values From'**.